# Is there a word or phrase that encompasses both infidelity and open relationships?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, terminology

When it comes to married couples or people in a dedicated intimate relationship, there are (essentially) two ways to describe one person in the relationship being intimate with someone other than their spouse/significant other.

If it's without their partner's consent or knowledge, it's Cheating or Infidelity.
If it's with their partner's knowledge and consent, that's an open marriage or (in some cases) cuckoldry.

But, is there a word, term or phrase that can be applied to both of these scenarios? Something that describes straying from one's 'commitment', but does not imply unfaithfulness or maliciousness?

EDIT: Finish this sentence-

> Michael cheated on his wife. Ben was intimate with another woman because he is in an open marriage with his wife. Both are _________.

Comment: I would not say that **cuckoldry** is an open situation, because the whole idea of the cuckoo's nesting habit is deceit.

Comment: @WeatherVane It can be in some cases, but google tells me you're right. Edited the question slightly.

Comment: With and or without consent? *Is there a word, term or phrase?* Doubtful there is such in English.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "cheating on somebody with their permission." Either you do or you don't—I don't see there being some kind of hybrid situation. Unless you mean that somebody is allowed to cheat within certain parameters (a list of people, places, circumstances, and so on), and somebody has cheated outside of those? But  that would still just be cheating—because the details weren't agreed to. You're going to have to be more specific about your scenario.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think you misunderstand me. I am looking for a term that you could apply to either situation. I know that they are mutually exclusive. Sort of like how you can eat food, or you can drink a liquid, but both of those situations can be covered by the word "consume". You can consume food, and you can consume a liquid. Is there a broader, vaguer term that can be applied to both cheating and open relationships.

Comment: Do you mean *rules*? You either break them (cheat) or you follow them (remain faithful—in whatever form).

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of it being non-exclusive? An example sentence may clear up the confusion, and is required under the rules.

Comment: @jimm101 Done...

Comment: Hm. Word, I dunno. Phrase, I can think of dozens (as can you, of course).

Comment: @RegDwigнt Such as...? That's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that the person being described has only one "spouse/significant other", then the word [***nonmonogamous***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonmonogamous) would fit:

> : not of, relating to, or practicing monogamy : not monogamous
>   
> //*nonmonogamous* couples
>   
> //*a nonmonogamous* relationship

(Merriam-Webster)

Cheating and open relationships can both be categorized as forms of nonmonogamy:

> I argue that transparency matters, and *consensual non-monogamy* (CNM) is qualitatively different from non-consensual non-monogamy, or cheating.

("[Seven Forms of Non-Monogamy](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-polyamorists-next-door/201407/seven-forms-non-monogamy)", by Elisabeth A. Sheff, *Psychology Today* Jul 22, 2014)

This word wouldn't work if you need to distinguish Micheal and Ben from someone who is in a committed polygamous relationship (or relationships) and is not intimate with anyone aside from his or her multiple spouses (or significant others).

Comment: While that word could complete the example sentence and be correct, I don't think it answers the question: "Something that describes straying from one's 'commitment', but does not imply unfaithfulness or maliciousness?" Someone who is nonmonogamous because they cheated is unfaithful.

Comment: On the contrart @birch that is very close to what I'm looking for. Calling a cheater nonmonogomous does not inherently imply maliciousness. If you look at an individual who has been intimate with someone other than their spouse, but with no other information, you do not know if they are cheating or if they are in an open relationship, so what I'm looking for is a word/phrase that can describe either/or without casting any blame or guilt upon the subject.

Comment: After writing a couple responses to @Nightstalker's comment, I now feel nonmonogamous works in this situation and am upvoting the answer. However, if in fact the evaluator knows only that (1) the person is married and (2) the person slept with someone not their spouse, I think even nonmonogamous implies they are in an open relationship. The most neutral way to note they slept with non-spouse is to say, "That person slept with someone who is not their spouse," which is why I think there is no exact word for this in English.

Comment: @Nightstalker  In a comment you said you want a word that can encompass both meanings of 1) open relationship or 2) monoamory/monogamy in the same sense that "consume" covers both drinking and eating. I understand if you're non-monogamous you can't be monogamous, so it doesn't cover one of your hypothetical circumstances, it doesn't cover both. Hogamus higamous I'm confused.

Comment: @Zebrafish: A cheater might have promised to be in a monogamous relationship, but cheating is not a monogamous *behavior.* Nightstalker wanted a word that can encompass both cheating and having sex with someone other than one's spouse/SO in the context of an open relationship. I don't understand what all the controversy or confusion is about ... would you describe a cheater (like Michael) as "monogamous"? Even if the relationship is theoretically monogamous, cheating means that the cheater is not being monogamous in practice (according to a commonly used definition of "monogamous").

Comment: @sumelic So are we talking non-monogamous behaviour or relationship? Ben cheated on his wife. Michael was intimate with another woman but it's OK because he's in an open relationship. Both behaviours of Ben and Michael are non-monogamous, but Ben's relationship is monogamous, because he cheated. The OP said in comment: "Is there a broader, vaguer term that can be applied to both cheating and open relationships." This seems to be about relationships, not behaviour. But in their example sentence they say Ben...Michael...Both are______, here a behaviour could fit. Non-monogamous would work.

Comment: @Zebrafish: The OP asked for "a word, term or phrase that can be applied to both of these **scenarios**" "to describe **one person in the relationship being intimate with someone other than their spouse/significant other**" and that would fit the sentence "Both [Michaell and Ben] are _________." Based on my reading of the question, it doesn't seem to be asking for a word to describe the relationships that Michael and Ben agreed to have with their spouses.

Comment: You're right, the example sentence doesn't call for a word describing relationship, but the comment the OP made to try and clarify did imply relationship, the one I quoted. Especially when you take into account that they said that they're mutually exclusive.  If they're talking about Ben and Michael's behaviour then there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not an English word that completes your example sentence.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer, unless you can provide demonstrable evidence of the *impossibility* of such a word existing, rather than you being unable to think of one.

Comment: Thanks @Chappo if that is how the answer rules work here I will follow that in the future

Comment: There may be confusion in understanding the question. If we're talking about a relationship I agree there's probably no word, but sumelic's answer of non-monogamous would fit for both Michael's and Ben's behaviour. The relationship/behaviour confusion was one I had, especially as in the comment the OP tried to clarify by saying they were mutually exclusive and asked for a "vaguer term that can be applied to both cheating and open relationships." And the example sentence was added after that comment.